# Help cleaning up square wave pulse signal

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, noise, comparator

I'm quite new to electronics in general.

My current circuit setup consists of an incoming sine wave. I use a comparator chip to compare this sin wave to a threshold which results in a square wave train, where the width of each square wave is changed by raising/lowering the threshold. I then use this output to trigger open/close a transistor to allow a separate signal through, which is the signal I wish to use. This setup works great when the frequency of the sin wave is low, however my issue is when running such that the incoming sin wave is higher frequency (on the order of 1-5 kHz) the signal looks like the image below.

Would there be any way to clean this up to remove the decreasing trains after the pulse? My initial though was perhaps the comparator chip, or the transistor cannot work at such frequencies but the spec sheet says they should be fine, and if this was the case I would expect a smooth tail not a drop to a value and then a decreasing tail.

[image]

edit:

Information that commenters asked for :)
Comparator chip: LM311P
Transistor: BC337

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsoNMk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you provide a schematic including the parts you're using? You can edit your post and use the Circuit Builder tool to draw a schematic right in your post.

Comment: Is this causing any issues in the consumer of the signal? Why do you think you need to "clean" it?

Comment: Take another look at the signal using a x10 probe.

Comment: Your schematic does not show the relationship between the "Experiment voltage" and Vcc or GND.  Without this, any analysis will be incomplete.  Please post a *complete* schematic.

Comment: The components shown do not match with the LM311. Please show the actual circuit that you are using.

Comment: @RussellH Sorry im not sure what you mean, here is the datasheet for the component https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm311.pdf, the circuit i followed is the example from that document such as the one on page 12 which appears the same as what ive drawn here

Comment: @AnalogKid Hi, sorry for not being complete (very new to this), but the experiment voltage does not have any relation to Vcc thats why i didnt include anything. The experiment voltage is a DC signal generated by a function generator.

Comment: That's a problem.  It they do not share a common GND or some other DC potential, there is no path for the Q2 base current to return to the driving circuit GND.  This can manifest in many different ways, most of them bad.